# How Control external FototCamera programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, dll, com, activex

I need to get photo from one external photo device (not webcam) connected to the pc, like compact photocamera o something like that, directly by code (I need to control the device).
Somebody know if there is some dll or some camera equiped with .dll to do that ?

Thamkyou

Piercarlo

Answer (score 0):

You might check out these links:
http://developer.olympus.com/cameras.html
http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/sdk_homepage